# Latex \Box in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, latex

i am trying to make a graph with matplotlib with an label, that includes the Latex command $\Box$. This throws me a bunch of errors, does anybody know how to do this? Do i have to include 'amssmyb' somehow?

The codeline looks like this

```
ax.loglog( w, PSD1, 'k:', label='$r_{J} = 100 \ M \Omega / \Box $')
```

Comment: what errors? what is the value of `text.usetex` in your `matplotlibrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FrancescoMontesano : I don't have enough reputation to post the following as a comment of your answer, so I'll post it here as an answer.

In my case, the suggestion of @FrancescoMontesano did not work, and I had to use :

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage{txfonts}'
```

Not sure of the reason why this worked on my configuration, but perhaps it is related to the matplotlib version I have ?

```
Matplot lib Version: 1.3.1
python 2.7.6
Linux 3.13.0-24
```

One annoying detail I noticed : whenever text.latex.preamble is defined, my latex compiler treats errors as warnings...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track: you need to include the `amssymb` package.

First you need to turn on `text.usetex` (that instruct matplotlib to use the system latex compiler) and then to add the `amssymb` package to `text.latex.preamble`.

1. If you need to do it just ones you can add the following in your python script:

   ```
   from matplotlib import rcParams
   rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
   rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amssymb}']
   ```
2. if you need it more often edit you [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) file like this:

   ```
   text.usetex         : True
   text.latex.preamble :  \usepackage{amssymb}
   ```

   Both entries should be already in the file, just uncomment them and edit as above

---

One last thing, that can save you from a lot of head ache:
When you use strings containing latex code in `matplotlib` (and more in general in python) use raw strings, so you don't have to remember to escape special characters, like `/`. I use one in my first example when I add `amssymb` to the preamble. For some info about them read [this piece of doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)