# Plot circle at the title in matplotlib python

Tags: matplotlib

I have a 2 line title and first line has a number at the end of the line.

Can we plot  a circle around the number?

Here is the code to generate the figure.

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
some_text = 'XXX'
any_number=15
title = '%s: %d\n YYY ZZZZ WWWWW' % (some_text,any_number)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=100)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=60, width=3, length=10, pad=40)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', labelsize=60, width=3, length=10, pad=40)

ax = plt.gca()

plt.title(title, fontsize=60, pad=40, loc='center', fontweight='semibold')
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax.set_facecolor('white')

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)

for edge_i in ['left']:
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_edgecolor("black")
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_linewidth(3)
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_bounds(0, 1)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.01, step=0.2))

data_list= np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8,0.85])
plt.bar(x, data_list, 0.9, color='indianred',edgecolor="black", linewidth=3,zorder=1)

plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',  # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=False,  # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top=False,  # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

figure_name = 'figure_with_circle.png'
figure_file = os.path.join('/Users/burcakotlu/Desktop',figure_name)
fig.savefig(figure_file, dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close(fig)
```

Here is the current figure and the wanted circle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thought is to include some latex packages like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904984/latex-box-in-matplotlib and then use a latex solution like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129086/how-can-i-draw-oval-circle-around-a-string

Answer (score 0):

One could use the following **without** ax.bar():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('title')
circle1 = plt.Circle((2,4.15), 0.2, color='k', clip_on=False, zorder=100, fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.set_xlim(0,4)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you get (2,4.15)?

Comment: Is there a way to get the position of the title?

Comment: there may be a hacky way to compute the title position relative to the coordinate origin. But as far as I know there is no option to get the title position using matplotlib functionality.

Comment: Also, circle and bar plot didn't work in my case. Can you also test with my code?

Comment: well, I see your issue. ax.bar and the method I proposed seemingly do not work together. The next best thing I can currently think of is to plot each bar as a rectangle using patches. Or maybe try the approach using latex @Keon proposed!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use bar plot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to plot circle together with bar plots without distorting  bars. Here is the code below:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
some_text = 'XXX'
any_number=15
title = '%s: %d\n YYY ZZZZ WWWWW' % (some_text,any_number)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12), dpi=100)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=60, width=3, length=10, pad=40)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', labelsize=60, width=3, length=10, pad=40)

ax = plt.gca()
number_of_xxx = '12'

anchored_text_number_of_xxx = AnchoredText(number_of_xxx,
                                                        frameon=False, borderpad=0, pad=0.1,
                                                        loc='upper right',
                                                        bbox_to_anchor=[0.95, 1.3],
                                                        bbox_transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
                                                        prop={'fontsize': 60,
                                                              'fontweight': 'semibold'})

ax.add_artist(anchored_text_number_of_xxx)


circle1 = patches.Circle((0.88, 1.25), radius=0.1, transform=ax.transAxes, zorder=100, fill=False, color='gold', lw=8, clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)

ax.set_title(title, fontsize=60, pad=40, loc='center', fontweight='semibold', zorder=50)
ax.set_facecolor('white')

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)

for edge_i in ['left']:
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_edgecolor("black")
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_linewidth(3)
    ax.spines[edge_i].set_bounds(0, 1)

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.01, step=0.2))

data_list= np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8,0.85])
ax.bar(x, data_list, 0.9, color='indianred',edgecolor="black", linewidth=3,zorder=1)

ax.tick_params(
    axis='x',  # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom=False,  # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top=False,  # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

figure_name = 'figure_with_circle.png'
figure_file = os.path.join('/Users/burcakotlu/Desktop',figure_name)
fig.savefig(figure_file, dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close(fig)
```